# Ajax response isn't showed on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My ajax is

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajax.ajax,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        status: 200,
        data: formdata,
        success: function(msg){
            $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
        }, 2000 );

        }
    });
```

This is the PHP part

```
function form(){ 

    global $wpdb;
    $table = cars;

    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        if($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
            continue;
        }

        $valid_ext = array( 'img' , 'png');
        $extension_upload = strtolower(  substr(  strrchr($file['name'], '.')  ,1)  );
        if ( in_array($extension_upload,$valid_ext) ) {
            $name_upload = uniqid() . $file['name'];
            $url_insert = trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . 'uploads';
            wp_mkdir_p($url_insert);
            $name_insert = trailingslashit($url_insert) . $name_upload;
            $action = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$name_insert);

            $data = array( 'customer_resume' => $name_upload );
            $format = array( '%s' );

            $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );  
            $msg_true = 'Upload ok ';

        } else {
            $msg_error = 'Upload error';
        }
    }

    $result = !isset($msg_error);
    $msg = array();

    if($result) {
        $msg['error'] = 'true';
        $msg['true'] = $msg_true;
    } else {
        $msg['error'] = 'false';
        $msg['false'] = $msg_error;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($msg);

}
```

And the HTML where I try to show the success or error message

```
<div id="error_message"></div>
<div id="success_message"></div>
```

When I click on Submit button I everything works fine and saved in database but there is no indication wheather is success or no. I've tried to add this `msg`'s but still nothing shows on page.

Comment: what is `data` here `$('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);` ? and how you change message as html ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut I'm not sure. I've tried different things to show it..

Comment: I'm not very familiar with js and just tried different "solutions" from different tutorials

Answer (score 2):

**PHP side:**

You need to print same variable for success and failure:

```
if($result) {
        $msg['error'] = 'true';
        $msg['msg'] = $msg_true;
    } else {
        $msg['error'] = 'false';
        $msg['msg'] = $msg_error;
    }
```

**JavaScript Side:**

The AJAX response will come as

```
data.error -> true or false.
data.msg -> Success or Error message depending upon program logic.

...
 success: function(data){
  $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data.msg);
...
```

Comment: Can you please see in what is there in javascript console?

Comment: Well, I don't see anything.

Comment: I've tried to add `console.log(data.msg);` inside success function but also doesn't show anything on the console

Comment: That is because you are trying to display the wrong thing, try console.log(msg.msg). The data being passed to the function is called msg, the JSON element of that is also called msg. The data aspect is the form data being sent to the PHP script.

Comment: @Jared, you are passing variable `msg` to function: `success()`, so you need to use `msg.msg` instead of `data.msg` as `data` is nowhere.

Comment: Changed it like this `success: function(msg){ $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(msg.msg); }` still nothing. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: I can't even display an `alert..` from inside the success function

Comment: Also in the network tab, response I see `{"error":"true","msg":"Upload ok "}0`

Answer (score 1):

What is hiding behind "ajax.ajax" ?

Also if you want to show your data you need to use "msg"

```
success: function(msg){
        $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(msg);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
    }, 2000 );

    }
```

Comment: Behind ajax.ajax is localize of wordpress - `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script`